# Scraping data without having to explicitly define each field to be scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape a page of data (using the Python Scrapy library) without having to define each individual field on the page. Instead I want to dynamically generate fields using the `id` of the element as the field name.

At first I was thinking the best way to do this would be to have a pipeline that collects all the data, and outputs it once it has it all.

Then I realised that I need to pass the data to the pipeline in an item, but I can't define an item as I don't know what fields it will need!

What's the best way for me to tackle this problem?

Comment: From your question history I'm going to guess this is the Python Scrapy library, am I right?

Comment: Right, is including the relevant tag enough? Or do I need to be clearer? .. ah, just noticed I forgot the Python tag, sorry :)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to clarify slightly in the question, but I've just added the python tag, so that makes it clearer.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26153461/832887) doesn't need any hacks. It works with newer versions of Scrapy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### **Update:**

The old method didn't work with [item loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and was complicating things unnecessarily. Here's a better way of achieving a flexible item:

```
from scrapy.item import BaseItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader

class FlexibleItem(dict, BaseItem):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    item = FlexibleItem()
    loader = ItemLoader(item)

    loader.add_value('foo', 'bar')
    loader.add_value('baz', 123)
    loader.add_value('baz', 'test')
    loader.add_value(None, {'abc': 'xyz', 'foo': 555})

    print loader.load_item()

    if 'meow' not in item:
        print "it's not a cat!"
```

**Result:**

```
{'foo': ['bar', 555], 'baz': [123, 'test'], 'abc': ['xyz']}
it's not a cat!
```

### **Old solution:**

Okay, I've found a solution. It's a bit of "hack" but it works..

A Scrapy Item stores the field names in a dict called `fields`. When adding data to an Item it checks if the field exists, and if it doesn't it throws and error:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key in self.fields:
        self._values[key] = value
    else:
        raise KeyError("%s does not support field: %s" %\
              (self.__class__.__name__, key))
```

What you can do is override this `__setitem__` function to be less strict:

```
class FlexItem(Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.fields:
            self.fields[key] = Field()

        self._values[key] = value
```

And there you go.

Now when you add data to an Item, if the item doesn't have that field defined, it will be added, and then the data will be added as normal.

Comment: How could that works? your Flixible item doesn't even have foo, bar, nor baz fileds ?

Comment: I wasn't able to get your solution working with the JSON exporter (Scrapy 0.21 here). Using a defaultdict for the fields attribute as shown in my answer seems to work better.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with OrderedDict so that the order of the items you add dynamically is preserved?

Answer (score 4):

This solution works with the exporters (`scrapy crawl -t json -o output.json`):

```
import scrapy

class FlexibleItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self.fields:
            self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field()
        super(FlexibleItem, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

**EDIT:** updated to work with latest Scrapy

Comment: `defaultdict(Field)` should be enough. Classes are callables.

Answer (score 3):

This works with version 0.24 and also allows Items to work with Item Loaders:

```
import scrapy
from collections import defaultdict

class FlexibleItem(scrapy.Item):
    fields = defaultdict(scrapy.Field)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # all keys are supported
        self._values[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer is late, but for those who still need a dynamic items using Scrapy (current version is 1), I created a repository on Github including an example.

Here you go

https://github.com/WilliamKinaan/ScrapyDynamicItems